# After a web scraping of urls of some images from instagram i want to obtain the full resolution images

Tags: python, json, image, url, web-scraping

I created some code in python that make a web scraping of the urls of the images of instagram given an hashtag using the json format.
I need to take the high resolution image, how is it possible?

I copied this part of text, because i don't know about json.

```
import json


def LoadURLS(soup):
    # Put all URLS into a variable
    script = soup.find('script', text=lambda t: t.startswith('window._sharedData'))
    page_json = script.text.split(' = ', 1)[1].rstrip(';')
    data = json.loads(page_json)
    global list
    list = []
    for post in data['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]['graphql']['hashtag']['edge_hashtag_to_media']['edges']:
        image_src = post['node']['thumbnail_resources'][1]['src']
        list.append(image_src)
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a built in function, but you can take a look at Instapy https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy

Comment: No, that tool is not what i'm searching for.